# How to export excel of grid from dialog or window(popup) in kendo

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-treeview, kendo-mobile

How to export excel of grid from dialog or window(popup) in kendo jquery(not use MVC or partial view)

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by using the built-in method `saveAsExcel`.

See the code snippet taken from the [Kendo documentation](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid/methods/saveasexcel):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>Kendo UI Snippet</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2019.1.220/styles/kendo.common.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2019.1.220/styles/kendo.rtl.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2019.1.220/styles/kendo.silver.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2019.1.220/styles/kendo.mobile.all.min.css"/>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2019.1.220/js/jszip.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2019.1.220/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  
<button id="export">Export to Excel</button>
<div id="grid"></div>
<script>
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
  columns: [
    { field: "name" },
    { field: "age" }
  ],
  dataSource: [
      { name: "Jane Doe", age: 30 },
      { name: "John Doe", age: 33 }
  ],
});
$("#export").click(function(e) {
    var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
    grid.saveAsExcel();
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```